# Race conditions in client synchronization

Tags: go, web, server, architecture, synchronization

I have a web app whose server creates a Client for each websocket connection. A Client acts as an intermediary between the websocket connection and a single instance of a Hub. The Hub maintains a set of registered clients and broadcasts messages to the clients. This works pretty well but the problem is that a client might miss events between when the server generates the initial state bundle that the client receives on connection and when the client is registered with the hub and starts receiving broadcast events.

My idea is to register the client with the hub before any information is fetched from the db. That would ensure that the client doesn't miss any broadcasts, though now it could receive messages that are already applied to the initial state it receives. To allow the client to disregard these messages I could include a monotonic timestamp in both the initial state bundle as well as broadcast events.

Can you think of a more elegant/simpler solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have used a write-ahead-log in the past to do something like this. In short, keep a ring buffer of messages in the hub. Then replay messages that where send to existing clients while the new one was initialized.

You can expose this concept to the clients too if you wish. That way you can implement efficient re-connects (particularly nice for mobile connections). When clients loose the websocket connection they can reconnect and say "Hey there, it's me again. Looks like we got interrupted. The last message I've seen was number 42. What's new?"

The following is from memory, so take this only as an illustration of the idea, not a finished implementation. In the intererest of brevity I've omited the select statements around `client.send`, for instance.

```
package main

import (
    "container/list"
    "sync"

    "github.com/gorilla/websocket"
)

type Client struct { // all unchanged
    hub  *Hub
    conn *websocket.Conn
    send chan []byte
}

type Hub struct {
    mu      *sync.RWMutex
    wal     list.List        // List if recent messages
    clients map[*Client]bool // Registered clients.

    register chan Registration // not a chan *Client anymore

    broadcast  chan []byte
    unregister chan *Client
}

type Registration struct {
    client *Client

    // init is a function that is executed before the client starts to receive
    // broadcast messages. All messages that are broadcast while init is
    // running will be sent after init returns.
    init func()
}

func (h *Hub) run() {
    for {
        select {
        case reg := <-h.register:
            // Take note of the most recent message as of right now. 
            // initClient will replay all later messages
            h.mu.RLock()
            head := h.wal.Back()
            h.mu.RUnlock()

            go h.initClient(reg, head)
        case client := <-h.unregister:
            h.mu.Lock()
            if _, ok := h.clients[client]; ok {
                delete(h.clients, client)
                close(client.send)
            }
            h.mu.Unlock()
        case message := <-h.broadcast:
            h.mu.Lock()
            h.wal.PushBack(message)
            // TODO: Trim list if too long by some metric (e.g. number of
            // messages, age, total message size, etc.)

            clients := make([]*Client, len(h.clients))
            copy(clients, h.clients)
            h.mu.Unlock()

            for client := range clients {
                // TODO: deal with backpressure
                client.send <- message
            }
        }
    }
}

func (h *Hub) initClient(reg Registration, head *list.Element) {
    reg.init()

    // send messages in h.wal after head
    for {
        h.mu.RLock()
        head = head.Next()
        if head == nil {
            // caught up
            h.clients[reg.client] = true
            h.mu.RUnlock()
            return
        }
        h.mu.RUnlock()

        // TODO: deal with backpressure
        reg.client.send <- head.Value.([]byte)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Peter. I had considered using some kind of queue too but not exactly the in the same way you propose. 

Wouldn't it still be possible that clients receive messages that are already applied to the initial state though?. For instance, if the server generates an event while reg.init was preparing the initial payload (fetching stuff from the db, etc.), the event could be already applied to this bundle but it will be sent again to the client after init returns, because it was not in the list of recent messages.

Comment: The assumption here was that you create the initial message from some sort of snapshot. If that's not the case then yes, there may be redundant messages. That's only a concern if the end result isn't idempotent though. But then again, is an inconsistent initial state really useful? It's hard to talk about this without knowing any details about your application.